# Adding tags to Gatsby Contentful blog

Tags: reactjs, tags, gatsby, blogs, contentful

I'm trying to add tags on blog posts, and I struggle to find a resource, which explain how to implement them.

The end goal is to get clickable tags, which leads to a page, where all posts with same tag appears in a list.

I'm using GatsbyJS with Contentful integration.

I have a file called article-post.tsx with the following code:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { documentToReactComponents } from "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer"

import Layout from "../components/layout/layout"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import SEO from "../components/layout/seo"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { BodyMain, H1 } from "../components/styles/TextStyles"

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    contentfulArticlePost(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      tags
      publishedDate(formatString: "Do MMMM, YYYY")
      featuredImage {
        fluid(maxWidth: 720) {
          ...GatsbyContentfulFluid
        }
      }
      body {
        json
      }
    }
  }
`

const ArticlePost = props => {
  const options = {
    renderNode: {
      "embedded-asset-block": node => {
        const alt = node.data.target.fields.title["en-US"]
        const url = node.data.target.fields.file["en-US"].url
        return <img alt={alt} src={url} className="embeddedImage" />
      },
    },
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title={props.data.contentfulArticlePost.title} />
      <Wrapper>
        <ImageWrapper>
          {props.data.contentfulArticlePost.featuredImage && (
            <Img
              className="featured"
              fluid={props.data.contentfulArticlePost.featuredImage.fluid}
              alt={props.data.contentfulArticlePost.title}
            />
          )}
        </ImageWrapper>
        <Title>{props.data.contentfulArticlePost.title}</Title>
        <Tags>
          {props.data.contentfulArticlePost.tags.map(tag => (
            <span className="tag" key={tag}>
              {tag}
            </span>
          ))}
        </Tags>
        <ContentWrapper>
          {documentToReactComponents(
            props.data.contentfulArticlePost.body.json,
            options
          )}
        </ContentWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default ArticlePost

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1.875rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 7rem 1.875rem;
  max-width: 900px;
`

const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
  .featured {
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
`

const Title = styled(H1)`
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
`

const Tags = styled.div`
margin: 0 auto;
.tag {
  background: #8636E4;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
`

const ContentWrapper = styled(BodyMain)`
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.6;

  .embeddedImage {
    padding: 50px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
`
```

It does give me the tags and I'm able to style them. Though I don't know how to get them clickable like links/buttons.

I have a file called gatsby-node.js, which contains the following code:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const response = await graphql(`
    query {
      allContentfulArticlePost {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  response.data.allContentfulArticlePost.edges.forEach(edge => {
    createPage({
      path: `/articles/${edge.node.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/article-post.tsx"),
      context: {
        slug: edge.node.slug,
        id: edge.node.id
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to create dynamic pages for each tag to create a valid link element. In your `gatsby-node.js` create a query to fetch all tags and create pages for each tag like:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const response = await graphql(`
    query {
      allContentfulArticlePost {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  response.data.allContentfulArticlePost.edges.forEach(edge => {
    createPage({
      path: `/articles/${edge.node.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/article-post.tsx"),
      context: {
        slug: edge.node.slug,
        id: edge.node.id
      },
    })
  })


  const tags= await graphql(`
    query {
      allContentfulArticlePost {
        edges {
          node {
            tags
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  tags.data.allContentfulArticlePost.edges.forEach(edge=> {
   let slugifiedTag= edges.node.tag.toLowerCase().replace("/^\s+$/g", "-");

    createPage({
      path: `/tag/${slugifiedTag}`,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/tag-post.tsx"), // your tagComponent
      context: {
        slug: edge.node.slug,
        tagName: edges.node.tag
      },
    })
  })    
}
```

Step by step, first of all, you need to retrieve all your tags from each blog in `tags` query.

Then, for each tag, you need to create a valid slug based on the name (i.e: `This Is a Sample Tag` will be converted to `this-is-a-sample-tag`, `slugifiedTag` in the sample). This is done in `edges.node.tag.toLowerCase().replace("/^\s+$/g", "-")`, the regular expression will match all-white spaces globally and will replace them by hyphens `replace("/^\s+$/g", "-")`. You may need to parse the `tags` edge to remove duplicates in order to avoid duplicated entries creation, creating a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) should work for you.

At this point, you'll have created all pages under `/tag/${slugifiedTag`} (i.e: `/tag/this-is-a-sample-tag`). So, you will need to change your `article-post.tsx` to point to the tag page:

```
<Tags>
  {props.data.contentfulArticlePost.tags.map(tag => {
   let slugifiedTag= edges.node.tag.toLowerCase().replace("/^\s+$/g", "-");

    return <Link className="tag" key={tag} to={slugifiedTag}>
      {tag}
    </Link>
  })}
</Tags>
```

*Note that you are repeating `slugifiedTag` function. You can avoid this by creating a tag entity in your CMS and adding a `name` and `slug` value. If you retrieve the slug in your `gatsby-node.js` query as well as in your template query, you can directly point to `<Link className="tag" key={tag} to={tag.slug}>`*. Following this example, the `name` will be `This is a Sample Tag` while the `slug` will be direct `this-is-a-sample-tag`.

What you last is to create a query in your `tag-post.tsx` that fetch all posts for each tag since you are passing via context the `slug` and the `tagName`. Your query should look like:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!, $tags: [String!]) {
    contentfulArticlePost(slug: { eq: $slug }, tags: { in: $tags}) {
      title
      tags
      publishedDate(formatString: "Do MMMM, YYYY")
      featuredImage {
        fluid(maxWidth: 720) {
          ...GatsbyContentfulFluid
        }
      }
      body {
        json
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Since `$tags` is an array, should be declared as `[String!]`. If you want to make the field non-nullable just add the exclamation mark (`!`) like `[String!]!`. Then you only need to filter the by tags that contain at least one tag: `tags: { in: $tags})`.

As I said, this should be improved and simplified by adding a tag entity in your CMS, with `name` and `slug` fields.

It's a broad question without knowing your data structure and your internal components but you get the main idea of the approach.