# adding clickable tags generated from contentful and gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful, graphiql

Pretty much follow this post [Adding tags to Gatsby Contentful blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594069/adding-tags-to-gatsby-contentful-blog/68371484#68371484) to a T but still can't find a reason why it's not working...

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!, $tag: [String!]) {
    contentfulBrunchPost(slug: { eq: $slug }, tag: { in: $tag }) {
      title
      slug
      tag
    }
  }
`

const TagPost = props => {
  return <h1>{props.data.contentfulBrunchPost.title}</h1>
}

export default TagPost
```

I get the error "Cannot read property 'contentfulBrunchPost' of undefined". Very new to graphiQL in contentful and gatsby so point in the right direction would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going to your local version of Graphiql at `http://localhost:8000/___graphql` and copying your exact query over. Does the query return data over there? If not, then your query may be incorrect. If it does return data, then you can drill down into it to determine the correct reference to use in your code.

Comment: appreciate the help! I get the error "message": "Variable \"$slug\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided." any point in right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Extending from:

> appreciate the help! I get the error "message": "Variable "$slug" of
> required type "String!" was not provided." any point in right
> direction? –

You've set the `slug` field as non-nullable (like required field) because of the exclamation mark (`!`). This means that must be provided from the `gatsby-node.js` file to the template (`TagPost`) so ensure that the field is always present or remove the nullability of the field to make it nullable:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String, $tag: [String!]) {
    contentfulBrunchPost(slug: { eq: $slug }, tag: { in: $tag }) {
      title
      slug
      tag
    }
  }
```

Your `createPage` function should look like:

```
createPage({
  path: `/tag/${slugifiedTag}`,
  component: path.resolve("./src/templates/tag-post.tsx"), // your tagComponent
  context: {
    slug: edge.node.slug,
    tag: edges.node.tag
  },
})
```